# SSH Configuration for multiple IP addresses (round-robin or randomized)

Tags: ssh, ip, ssh-config, round-robin

I have a machine that I am using as an SSH jumphost which has multiple ethernet ports each of which has its own IP address (192.168.1.22 and 192.168.1.178 in case it matters). I use SSH for a lot of stuff, in particular large file transfer. I would like to evenly distribute SSH traffic amongst these two ethernet ports. I don't really care if its a round-robin configuration or if every time I connect it picks one of the two IP addresses at random so long as the traffic is more-or-less evenly distributed.

On top of this, the jumphost is accessible via SSH from the outside world with two port-forward configurations, one port (let's say 22) points to the first IP address and another (let's say 2222) points to the other IP address. Its arguably more important that I figure out how to "round-robin" between the two ports rather than the two IP addresses since the jumphost matters most when I am outside my network.

Is there an SSH config example I could use for something like this? I've been unable to find one. Potentially using the Match keyword? I've tried adding multiple IP addresses to the Host field, but it just uses the first one and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after digging into this for a bit, I figured out a solution.

I wrote two scripts, one called `on_lan` and the other called `seconds_are_even`. I then execute these scripts to determine which connection parameters should be used.

The scripts are written in python, and are pretty simple:

**on_lan**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                       
from ipaddress import ip_address, ip_network
from itertools import chain
from sys import exit

from psutil import net_if_addrs

def ip_addr(candidate: str):
    try:
        return ip_address(candidate)
    except Exception:
        return None

def on_lan() -> bool:
    IPS = {ip_addr(a.address) for a in chain.from_iterable(addrs for addrs in net_if_addrs().values()) if ip_addr(a.address)}
    return any(ip in ip_network('192.168.XXX.0/24') for ip in IPS) # note that for this to work well, you don't wanna use a common LAN IP address range like 192.168.1.0/24

exit(0 if on_lan() else 1)
```

**seconds_even**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from time import time
from sys import exit

T = int(time())

exit(0 if T % 2 else 1)
```

These two scripts can be combined in 4 different ways. Either we're on the LAN or we're not, and either we're even or not. So my SSH config looks like this:

```
Host myserver.b
     ...

Match host *.b !exec ~/.ssh/scripts/on_lan !exec ~/.ssh/scripts/seconds_are_even
     Hostname <DOMAIN NAME>
     Port 2222

Match host *.b !exec ~/.ssh/scripts/on_lan exec ~/.ssh/scripts/seconds_are_even
     Hostname <DOMAIN NAME>
     Port 2222

Match host *.b exec ~/.ssh/scripts/on_lan !exec ~/.ssh/scripts/seconds_are_even
     Hostname 192.168.1.22
     Port 22

Match host *.b exec ~/.ssh/scripts/on_lan exec ~/.ssh/scripts/seconds_are_even
     Hostname 192.168.1.178
     Port 22

Host *.b
     ServerAliveInterval 30
     ServerAliveCountMax 2
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keys.d/id_ed2551
```

This way, when I execute `ssh server.b`, we first figure out whether we're on the LAN or not, and then whether the current seconds are even or not. If we're on the LAN we use the local IP, otherwise we use the public domain name. Then we use the current seconds as a randomizer to switch between the two possible interfaces that my SSH bastion has.